# i wrote a code to get optional data from interactive broker's api in tws into a pandas data frame but I am getting Error 200

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading

I wrote a code to get optional data from interactive broker's api in tws into a pandas data frame but I am getting Error 200
I am using interactive brokers api ib_insync
and there trading work station
I cannot figure out the problem

please help me to solve this issue I have the api subscription

```
ib.connect()
ib.sleep(2)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
# Wait for a few seconds to establish the connection
sp500_strikes ={
                'AAL': [17],
                'AAPL': [187.5, 192.5],
                'ADM': [90, 91],
                'AEP': [85, 87.5],
                'AMD': [118, 122, 170],
                'JPM': [135, 66, 56],
                'VMC': [102],
                'VZ': [187.5]
            }

# Inside the loop where you're creating option contracts and requesting market data
data = []
quantity =13
# Request real-time market data for options
for symbol, strikes in sp500_strikes.items():
    for strike in strikes:
        for right in ['C', 'P']:  # Call and Put options
            contract = Option(symbol, '20230901', strike=strike, right=right, exchange='SMART', currency='USD')
            ticker = ib.reqMktData(contract, snapshot=True)
            ib.sleep(0.1)  # Wait briefly for data reception
            
            # Extract desired fields from the ticker object
            cmp_value = ticker.last
            bid_premium = ticker.bid
            ask_premium = ticker.ask
            
            # Calculate other values
            value = cmp_value * quantity  # Replace with actual quantity
            capture = 0.8 * cmp_value
            cs_strike = cmp_value - (0.1 * cmp_value)
            cb_strike = cmp_value * 0.95
            sell_premium = 0.9 * ask_premium
            actual_cb = cmp_value * 0.95
            diff = actual_cb - cb_strike
            
            # Append the data to the list
            data.append({
                'Symbol': symbol,
                'Expiry': '20230915',
                'Strike': strike,
                'Right': right,
                'CMP': cmp_value,
                'Value': value,
                'Capture': capture,
                'CS Strike': cs_strike,
                'CB Strike': cb_strike,
                'Bid Premium': bid_premium,
                'Ask Premium': ask_premium,
                'Sell Premium': sell_premium,
                'Actual CB': actual_cb,
                'Diff': diff
            })

            

            
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
# Reset the display options
pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
pd.reset_option('display.expand_frame_repr')
```